# line segment across bar plot with multiple series (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a bar plot with multiple series, with lines connecting the first and last values of each series. I'm trying to figure out a way to anchor the lines to the middle of the respective bars rather than the center of each pair of bars. So what I have is this:

```
d <- data.frame(cat1=rep(c('Ape','Cat','Dog'),2),
measurement=c(8,7,2,9,5,4),
cat2=c('A','A','A','B','B','B'))

ggplot(d,aes(cat1,measurement,fill=cat2)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_segment(aes(x='Ape',y=8,xend='Dog',yend=2)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x='Ape',y=9,xend='Dog',yend=4))
```

This gives me decent results but ideally I'd be able to line up the two lines to their respective value series more clearly. I know I could futz with the x and xend values but having some automated way to do this would be convenient.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a position function to adjust the segments:

```r
d <- data.frame(cat1=rep(c('Ape','Cat','Dog'),2),
                measurement=c(8,7,2,9,5,4),
                cat2=c('A','A','A','B','B','B'))


library(ggplot2)

ggplot(d, aes(cat1, measurement, fill = cat2)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 'Ape', y=8, xend='Dog', yend=2), position = position_nudge(x = -0.225))+
  geom_segment(aes(x = 'Ape', y=9, xend='Dog', yend=4), position = position_nudge(x = 0.225))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Good Job. One remark: To put the starting and end point in the center of the bars I would suggest to nudge by .225 which is one fourth of the default bar width of .9.

Comment: @stefan thanks for this I noticed this shortly after posting the answer and changed the width of the bar to 1